# count likes clicks in my website

Tags: dns, facebook-like

I have a website - uxonbeer.co.il and I can see that about 300 facebook users likes it.
The problem is that lately, I have enabled browsing the website at WWW.uxonbeer.co.il and I see no likes. 
How can I resolve it and see all the likes in both WWW.uxonbeer.co.il and uxonbeer.co.il?

Answer (score 0):

This is only a partial answer, but it may help:

Facebook associate your OGP data with the ID number that they assign to your page, see here:
http://graph.facebook.com/10150326195658030

But the "like" or "share" count is not associated with this ID number. It's associated with the actual URL of the page. So you have two distinct counts, stored in the Facebook social graph here: 
https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.uxonbeer.co.il/
and 
https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://uxonbeer.co.il/

Can anyone finish the answer by telling us how to use a single count for both URLs?

David